# What is the correspondence between Fermat's Little Theorem and the SICP implementation?

Tags: math, scheme, sicp

*Structure and Interpretation of Programs* defines Fermat's Little Theorem thus:

> If n is a prime number and a is any positive integer less than n, then
>   a raised to the nth power is congruent to a modulo n.
>
> (Two numbers are said to be congruent modulo n if they both have the
>   same remainder when divided by n. The remainder of a when divided by n
>   is also referred to as the remainder of a modulo n, or simply a modulo
>   n.

Based on that description, I write this code:

```
(define (fermat-test a n) 
  (congruent? (expt a n) a n))

(define (congruent? x y n) 
  (= (modulo x n) 
     (modulo y n)))
```

Later, SICP says this:

> This leads to the following algorithm for testing primality: Given a
>   number n, pick a random number a < n and compute the remainder of a^n
>   modulo n. If the result is not equal to a, then n is certainly not a
>   prime.

and gives this code:

```
(define (fermat-test) 
  (define (try-it)
    (= (expmod a n n) a))
  (try-it (+ 1 (random (- n 1)))))

(define (expmod base exp m) 
  (cond ((= exp 0) 1) 
        ((even? exp) 
          (remainder (expmod base (/ exp 2) m) m)) 
        (else 
          (remainder (* base (expmod base (- exp 1) m)) m))))
```

where `expmod` is "a procedure that computes the exponential of a number modulo another number".

I don't understand the correspondence between this code and the first definition of Fermat's theorem. I understand "a raised to the nth power is congruent to a modulo n" as: `a^n modulo n = a modulo n`. But SICP's code seems to imply `a^n modulo n = a`. The condition in the `fermat-test` procedure does not include `a modulo n`. Of course, their implementation works, so I must be misunderstanding.

Please note, this is not a confusion about recursive versus iterative processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition in the test has `a` rather than `a modulo n` because if `a < n` then `a modulo n` *is* `a`, so that the `modulo n` is superfluous.

What they are really testing is if `n` is a [Fermat pseudoprime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_pseudoprime). It doesn't work as a full-fledged test for primality (and SICP doesn't claim that it does) but the ideas involved in the test ultimately lead to the fully practical [Miller-Rabin test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test).

Comment: Thanks for explaining! Do you know why the definition would include congruency if it also stipulates that a < n? It seems like the Fermat test is more commonly formulated a different way, as they allude to in the bit about the Miller-Rabin test, so I had trouble finding information about this formula.

Answer (score 0):

(expt a n) will compute a very large number

(expmod a n n) will compute a number in the range 0 to n

the two values will be congruent (modulo n).

The reason for using expmod is that fermat-test can be made much faster by using it. The fermat-test function will give the same result either way.

Comment: Thanks for replying. The question was why the SICP code does not test for congruency.